# Return all records in Salesforce TASK table with Informatica

Tags: salesforce, informatica

I am trying to copy all records in the TASK table in Salesforce using Informatica. I have selected the option in Informatica to return all records. When I check the object in Salesforce it shows 10 million records, but Informatica only returns 4 million. In my research I have seen mention that old records are moved into "activityhistory" but I am not able to access that with Informatica. I am looking for ideas on where the data could be so I can pull it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you could update records in this proccess.

You need to create a field to control what tasks you get already with informatica cloud proccess.
You can create a DATE field get the records WHERE this field equals to NULL then update TODAYS date in this field.

So your proccess needs these steps:

- GET RECORDS WHERE DATE EQUALS NULL
- UPDATE IN SALESFORCE THE RECORDS THAT YOU GET PREVIOULY
  -... DO THE SAME UNTIL THE END OF RECORDS

Check bulkfy options to get massive records.

I hope help you.